# Use external power - nodemcu 0.9

Tags: nodemcu, battery

I'd like to deploy my project so I'm looking for a way to power the nodemcu.
I'd like to know if there's a way to power it with a 9V battery **without any other external circuit**.

Until now I've found information for the nodemcu 1.0 and it supports up to 20V on the VIN port. Here's the article I read: 
http://henrysbench.capnfatz.com/henrys-bench/arduino-projects-tips-and-more/powering-the-esp-12e-nodemcu-development-board/

I'd like to use the two port: 5V and GND but I'm not sure, here there is no VIN port and I'd prefer to not burn my board. 
Are there any better way to power my project?

Comment: you can feed more than 5v in, especially for short periods of time.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the 0.9 uses the SPX3819 regulator. That can run with up to 16V on the input, so 9V on the 5V pin (*as long as USB never gets connected*) should work fine.

**Except:** 9V PP3 batteries are useless. If it can even provide enough power to run the board (which is doubtful) it won't last more than a few hours.  You would have to ensure that you use *very very* deep sleep mode to get any semblence of longevity out of it.

The 3.3V regulator will be throwing away half to two-thirds of the power as heat. So wasteful. You would be better off investing in a 3.3V switch-mode ("buck") regulator circuit (cheap on eBay) to directly power the 3.3V pin of the board instead of 9V into the on-board regulator.

Comment: Thank you, I'm actually using DeepSleep in fact the board should sleep more or less for 6 hours, wake for few seconds (1 min max) and the go to deep sleep again. I cannot use a power bank because when the board is in deep sleep because it stop to provide power

Comment: About the 3.3V regulator, does the AMS1117-3.3 is ok? From here I read that the Vin-Vout should be between 1.5V and 12V, is it correct?
http://www.advanced-monolithic.com/pdf/ds1117.pdf

Comment: That is just as inefficient. But it can handle more current before it melts.

Comment: You want to look for a "UBEC" (that's the magic word). Something like [this](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/AEO-X3-Pro-Input-7-2-21V-Output-3-3V-3-5A-UBEC-BEC-for-RC-Models/222809010433).